# Scrapy: Returning list of ids after crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a custom spider to recursively scape pages of a website and store the details of each crawl in my postgres database:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        with transaction.manager:
            crawl = Crawl()
            crawl.url = response.request.url
            crawl.response_body = response.body
            Session.add(crawl)
            Session.flush()

        if len(response.css('.pager-next')) == 1:
            # build url for the next page to crawl
            # ...
            yield scrapy.Request(url=full_url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

The problem is that I want to get back a list of ids for the crawls that were added to the database, which another function can use.

```
def scrape_website():
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start() # <-- how to return crawl ids?

    parse_crawls(crawl_ids)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't override `__init__` wo calling super, move `start_urls` to class attr, remove parse method, rename `parse_page` to `parse`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Item Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) to store your data in Postgresql

Look at `pipelines.py` example from [this article](https://minhdanh.me/scraping-web-data-with-scrapy/)

```
import psycopg2
from scrapy_example_com.items   import *


class ScrapyExampleComPipeline(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='scrapy_example_com', user='postgres')
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    # check item type to decide which table to insert
    try:
      if type(item) is CustomerItem:
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO customers (id, firstname, lastname, phone, created_at, updated_at, state) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (item.get('id'), item.get('firstname'), item.get('lastname'), item.get('phone'),  item.get('created_at'), item.get('updated_at'), item.get('state'), ))
      elif type(item) is CategoryItem:
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO categories (id, name) VALUES(%s, %s)""", (item.get('id'), item.get('code'), ))
      self.connection.commit()
      self.cursor.fetchall()

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
      print "Error: %s" % e
    return item
```

And don't forget to update your `settings.py`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
  'scrapy_taskeme.pipelines.ScrapyExampleComPipeline': 300
}
```